# Windows 10 to Linux Samba over VPN, strange directory listing issue

Tags: vpn, linux-networking, samba, network-share, windows-10

We have a client that has two sites connected via VPN, one of the users has moved from one to the other taking their computer with them.

When they connect to the server at the old site it connects fine but they don't see the full directory listing of the SAMBA share on the linux server only one folder is visible, which they can successfully access.

If we move the computer back it works just fine.

Other users on the same site have no issue.

Different login credentials produce the same fault on that system.

The login credentials on that site on different systems work as expected.

Seems to be sepcific to that system.

Anyone else experienced anything like this?

Is there some sort of residual caching of something going on

Windows 10 client -
Ubuntu 18.04.3 Server -
Samba Version 4.7.6-Ubuntu -
Remote IP Range 192.168.2.0/24 (client) -
Local IP Range 192.168.1.0/24 (server) -
The VPN is managed by the VOIP company but appears to function with all other clients fine.

Comment: I would suggest looking into the security descriptors in Windows 10. Do the folders in the share all have the same security descriptors on them as viewed by the Windows 10 client, or are there local and domain descriptors mixed?

Answer (score 1):

It was caused by offline synching being enabled...

Once disabled the share appears correctly.

[Method to disable sync here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/122727-enable-disable-offline-files-windows.html)